# Send array value on Javascript but it show as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, express

I count number of result from database and send as 'TotalItems'

```
mysql_crawl.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` WHERE MATCH(data_index) AGAINST("'+n+'") ', function(error, count) {
    var r = count[0];
    var totalItems = r,
    res.render('result.html', {
                totalItems: totalItems
                })
    });
```

I try running console.log on r, result is

```
RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(*)': 25 }
```

but when I run <% totalItems %> on javascript, it show as

```
[object Object]
```

How can I show object as number?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Answer (score 5, accepted):

totalItems is object, you can access its values by `totalItems['COUNT(*)']`

Answer (score 1):

Telling a template engine to render an object will cast the object into a string. This is done by looking at the object to see if it implements a `toString()` method and if not will walk the object's prototype chain till it finds one.

In you example the closest `toString` is on the top level primitive `Object`. This implementation simply outputs `[object Object]`. There is excellent information about this is [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

You could implement your own `toString` and even wrap the `count` object in a custom object with a name and custom `toString`. But in your case you were given a generic object and am (presumably) not at the level of abstracting code in more object oriented design patterns. In this case it is simply easier to wrap your template code use with `JSON.stringify` which will serialize any object into a string containing JSON data which is human readable for developers:

```
<% JSON.stringify(totalItems, null, 2) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` comes from the `.toString()` function. Example: `{ a: 1 }.toString()`.

You need to encapsulate it in `JSON.stringify(...)`, example: `JSON.stringify({ a: 1 })` => `{ "a": 1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

For full printing of an `Object` or `Array`, you can use:

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
```

This returns a `String` representation of the given Object as a tree.

For example:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: {d: 4}}
```

becomes:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
        "d": 4
    }
}
```